# SQL Server Management Studio cannot find error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have recently installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17. I worked on it for like 1 hour or so, created my own database and just as I was going to create a table, my laptop gave me a kind of BSOD screen (I have Windows 10 btw). Well it showed me that it was collecting data for the error and then restarted. Since then, I couldn't start SSMS ever again. It keeps giving me "cannot find one or more components, please reinstall error" and I tried literally everything to fix it. I reinstalled the program. I uninstalled VS Isolated Shell then repaired SSMS. I even removed the /14.0_config file from the registers, but still no result, I still can't enter the program anymore. Do you think I've done something wrong during these steps or should I try something else?

Comment: Did you try to locate the SSMS error log to identify the offending component ? Also, review Windows Application Event Log, just in case.

Comment: how do I locate the error log?